# Use SimpleMembershipProvider as Membership Provider in IIS Manager

Tags: iis, .net-framework, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net

In IIS Manager you have the ability to manage the registered users and the roles available. By default, only a few providers are trusted such as AspNetMembershipProvider and some others. When you have a different provider set up in your Web Application it doesn't work. It warns you that you have to add the assembly to the GAC and add the library to the trusted providers in a config file (administration.config).

So I went on, and added the assembly (WebMatrix.WebData) to the GAC and set the config file up so that it also allows non-trusted providers. But there are two problems:

1. Every time you open the .NET Users pane in IIS Manager it warns you that the provider gets more privileges than in the application. This would be solved by  adding this to the 'trusted' list but I can't get that to work.
2. It doesn't work. If I allow the Provider to run with higher privileges, it stops working and gives the error that you have to call WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection before you call any other method. How do I get IIS Manager to run that command before it calls any other?

Comment: Any luck with a solution for this?